# How can you refresh all regions in Beaker cache in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

I am trying to setup caching on a web server I have built using Pyramid. I am using [pyramid_beaker](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_beaker/en/latest/index.html), which creates a back-end to use [Beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) for caching.

I have been using cached region decorators to implement the caching.

A sample cached region looks like this:

```
def getThis(request):
    def invalidate_data(getData,'long_term',search_term):
         region_invalidate(getData,'long_term',search_term)
    @cached_region('long_term')
    def getData(search_term):
         return response
    try:
         request.matchdict['refresh']
    except:
         pass
    search_term = request.matchdict['searchterm']
    return getData(search_term)
```

Now that the caching works fine and I can trigger cache refresh on each region, I was wondering how I might refresh ALL regions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beaker has a dict object of all CacheManagers that can be used to iterate over to clear each:

```
from beaker.cache import cache_managers
for _cache in cache_managers.values():
    _cache.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were saving to file, you could probably just erase the folder containing all caches. This is probably not the best solution but it should be pretty fast and effective.